# Who was the first Korean to compete in the Olympics?

Tags: trivia, olympics

The Wikipedia article [South Korea at the Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Korea_at_the_Olympics) mentions that the first people from Korea to win an Olympic medal were in 1936, competing for the empire of Japan. But what about the first people from Korea to compete at all, either competing for the empire of Japan or the Korean empire?

[Japan at the Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_at_the_Olympics), [North Korea at the Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea_at_the_Olympics), and [Korea at the Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korea_at_the_Olympics) don't have any information about this.